# Scrapy - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to scrape a website.
Although the scraping process is working just fine. However, I'm getting error logs on the command line:

```
2017-08-21 03:47:22 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler:
 <bound method ?.item_scraped of <scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter obje
ct at 0x00000000041DD908>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 150, in m
aybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in ro
bustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\feedexport.py", line 224
, in item_scraped
    slot.exporter.export_item(item)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\exporters.py", line 93, in export_i
tem
    data = self.encoder.encode(itemdict) + '\n'
  File "c:\python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "c:\python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 264, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 5517: invali
d start byte
```

What might be causing this, I'm using scrapy selector objects to scrape data. I would like to get rid of these errors being shown on the command line.
EDIT: The site is using `iso-8859-1` encoding

Comment: Can you try setting [`FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-encoding) to `latin1` in your settings?

Comment: Thanks a lot! this solved most of the errors but now I'm getting the same error for latin1 codec (although a lot less). Is this a problem with the website encoding?

Comment: Can you share some code on how you populate your items? Are you using all-Unicode strings? Are you perhaps converting string to bytes with some encoding as values for your item fields? The default JSON exporter should not have any trouble serializing items with Unicode strings.

Comment: I'm using `response.css("h1::text").extract_first()` syntax to extract all the data and later use the returned unicode object to populate items.

Comment: I'm curious in seeing what the item is when the exporter is called. Could you add a debug `print("%r" % item)` call in your callback to see?